# Checkbox (bool) can not be toggled in gridbox. C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, .net-3.5

I have a DataGridView with a binding source to an interface that has a bool. When I click the checkbox that is created in the grid, nothing happens. The value is not set and the box does not get checked.

However, and this gets very case specific, if I set a binding source to a completely different control in the same view then the checkbox in the first control is possible to click. The downside to this is that every DataGridView when loaded has a large portion of it that is completely black.

Comment: I would recommend posting soem code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry I have no point to make this as a comment.
anyway did you check that the column of the DataGridView is set as readOnly = false, or enable = true.

check it also in run time, make a break point before and after doing the binding and see how your grid is set up.

Also if you can give some code maybe will see some other issue that can make this happen.

good luck

Comment: It was the column that was set to readonly = true.

Any idea what might cause the black parts of the grid?

Comment: Didnt understand very well that part.
instead of bidding your datagridView you are biding an other control (which control?) to the source and you get black spots in the datagridView?
can you add some code and maybe a screen shot to see what you mean when you say completely black?

Comment: [Image of the black parts](http://i.imgur.com/kzxBvbT.png)


It seems after some investigation that some code is not ran. There is too much domain specific code so I don't think it will help any to post it.


The thing that triggers this is the following:
'_viewModel.objectProperty1 = _someController.myClassProperty1;'

This is just one of many of those lines of code, but this specific one has an 'object' in the viewModel and a local class in the controller.

If I comment out this line of code, everything runs fine and looks good, but with this code you get the result in the picture.

Comment: Hannot, Im sorry but I have no idea what can be, maybe it will be good idea for you to post a new question about this specific with the screen shoot and this information, hope someone with more experience than me could help you.
good luck